# Nested for loop with inner functions

Tags: javascript, cordova

In javascript For loop it's works fast and inner functions are not called. I am trying to store images in database using cordova. In my code for loop works fast and finished but I didn't get any base64 images.

```
for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
{
    var cat_img = res.Catalogue[0].Catalogue_img;
    var catalogue_image_id = cat_img[i].catalogue_image_id;
    var catalogue_image = cat_img[i].catalogue_image;

    getBase64FromImage(catalogue_image,function (baseData64) {
        console.log("baseData64===="+baseData64);
        insertPageData (catalogue_image, catalogue_image_id);
     },function (error) {
        console.log("error====="+error);
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is `console.log("baseData64===="+baseData64);` working as expected ?

Comment: Is `getBase64FromImage` an async function?  If so, the `for` loop is guaranteed to finish before either of the callback functions are called in any of the loop iterations.

Comment: @JamesThorpe is correct, since getBase64FromImage is async your loop ends before image is returned.

Comment: yeah I got  console.log("baseData64===="+baseData64); after all for loop iteration is completed. and I got only for 1st image. any solution?

Comment: I tried lots of with while loop, recursion but still i am facing same issue. I am really frustrate due to this. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback "function (baseData64)" will be executed only when the image is downloaded and converted to base64. At that point, the value of "calalogue_image" and "catalogue_image_id" will contain the value of the last element in the loop - with "i = pages.length"

That is, your for loop finishes probably before even the first image is downloaded.

Actually I think the valid behaviour is that you should see only the last image, with "i = pages.length" in the database.

Try this

```
var processImage = function (cImg,cImgId){
    var catalogueImage = cImg;
    var catalogueImageId = cImgId;
    return function (baseData64) {
        console.log("baseData64===="+baseData64);
        insertPageData (catalogueImage, catalogueImageId);
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
{
    var cat_img = res.Catalogue[0].Catalogue_img;
    var catalogue_image_id = cat_img[i].catalogue_image_id;
    var catalogue_image = cat_img[i].catalogue_image;
    getBase64FromImage(catalogue_image, 
            processImage(catalogue_image, catalogue_image_id) ,
            function (error) {
                console.log("error====="+error);
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's really very helpful. :)